# python - Running tox + nosetests on a Python 3.2 testenv

Tags: python, testing, python-3.x, automated-tests, nose

I've been trying to implement a single-source testing system that allows automated testing across multiple Python versions using tox + nosetests.

Problem is, I can't get it working whenever I test against Python 3.2. Everything works fine if I exclude Python 3.2.

Here's my `tox.ini`:

```
[tox]
envlist = py25,py26,py27,py32,pypy,jython

[testenv]
commands =
    nosetests []
deps =
    nose
    mock

[testenv:py32]
commands =
    nosetests []
```

and my `~/.noserc`:

```
[nosetests]
verbosity=2
with-doctest=1
```

I've set the `use_2to3` flag to `True` in my setup.py, but this error keeps showing up: `NameError: global name 'basestring' is not defined`. It seems that I'm missing some setting that should make `2to3` work, but I don't know what it is.

Additionally, I've tried replacing `nosetests []` with `python setup.py test` in the `testenv:py32` setting. Unfortunately, not only the same error keeps showing up, it also introduces another error: `Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`.

Any pointers?

EDIT: added the code in `setup.py`, in case it's useful:

```
# handle python 3
if sys.version_info >= (3,):
    use_2to3 = True
else:
    use_2to3 = False
```

and somewhere in `setup()`: `use_2to3 = use_2to3`

Comment: If you're using 2to3, you need to ensure it runs `setup.py` and tests against the version that builds, rather than testing against the main source. I've not used `tox`, but generally you can run `python setup.py build`, then change into the build directory, and run nosetests.

Comment: I think that's what tox is doing. It makes isolated virtualenvs for these separate python versions/implementations. E.g., it spits out an error if I don't include ``from __future__ import with_statement`` in a python2.5 env, but not in python2.7. 

The ``2to3`` conversion seems to be working, but for some reason ``tox`` is not testing against it automatically...

Comment: Make sure it's not running `nosetests` from the source directory, which will have the untranslated code.

Comment: Ah yes, I think I got it working. I ended up specifying the py32 env's ``site-packages`` directory manually in my ``tox.ini``. Not the most elegant solution given that I don't have to do this for the other testenvs, but it's good for now. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, glad you worked something out. I'm not sure there's an elegant way to test using 2to3, although maybe `distribute` has some tricks...

Answer (score 1):

You might use something like this in the `[testenv]` section:

```
changedir = {envtmpdir}
commands = nosetests package  # "package" is import name of the package under test
```

or if you have tests in a separate directory than the package:

```
changedir = tests  # directory where tests are living
commands = nosetests []
```

This should prevent nose from picking up the wrong package version.